# Find acronyms throughout Word document using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to find acronyms throughout a Word document using VBA in Excel.

```vb
Sub HighlightAcronyms()
    
    Dim rng As Range, r2 As Range
    
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    Set r2 = ActiveDocument.Content
    
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "<[A-Z]{2,}>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Format = False
        
        Do While .Execute
            'look two characters past the found acroynm
            r2.Start = rng.End + 1
            r2.End = rng.End + 3
            Debug.Print rng.Text, r2.Text
            
            'highlight if r2 has a "(" otherwise clear highlight
            rng.HighlightColorIndex = IIf(r2.Text Like "*(*", _
                                          wdAuto, wdYellow)
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

On `.find` I get a compile error

> Argument not optional

I attempted to declare `.find`.

Comment: Is this tagged *Excel* for a reason? This looks like *Word* to me. Or do you want to run this code in Excel but want to work on a word document?

Comment: If you are working in Word, [this may be useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find)

Comment: Ah, I guess I understand: You have this code in Excel, but you want to work with a Word document. Now VBA thinks that you want to use Excel methods, and `Find` in Excel is a complete different thing than `Word` and needs parameter when called.

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/19395-acronym-finder-macro-microsoft-word.html, https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/42313-acronym-definiton-list-generator.html & https://www.msofficeforums.com/excel-programming/48007-adapting-macropods-acronym-word-vba-code-excel.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical code snippet to run Word VBA code with Excel VBA. Please update as needed.

```
Sub WordVBAinExcel()
    Dim doc As Object ' Word.Document
    Dim wordApp As Object ' Word.Application

    On Error Resume Next
    ' Try to get the existing Word application
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        ' If Word is not already running, create a new instance
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word is not installed or accessible.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    wordApp.Visible = True ' Set to True if you want to see the Word application during execution
    ' Open the Word document (Replace "C:\Path\to\Your\Document.docx" with the actual path)
    'Set doc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Path\to\Your\Document.docx")
    
    'Your Code
    Dim rng As Object, r2 As Object ' it is wordApp.Range not Excel.Range
    
    Set rng = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    Set r2 = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    ' ....

    'Your Code

    ' Quit the Word application
    wordApp.Quit
    ' Clean up the objects
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Task completed.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code has exactly the same errors as the original: `Dim rng As Range, r2 As Range` declares the variables as Excel ranges. I really wish people would stop using late binding when working across the Office suite. There are no advantages to it, only disadvantages such as no IntelliSense, no checking for syntax and compilation errors.

Comment: In existence, there is reason. Early binding is not always superior to late binding. When users have different Excel releases, such as some using Excel 2021 while others are on Excel 2019, early binding can become problematic. Users are required to modify references in the Visual Basic Editor, which can be challenging for business users. Anyway, thanks to point out the typo.

Comment: If you’ve done your development correctly it isn’t an issue. The rule has always been to develop in the oldest version you need to support, then test in each newer version. That way the references always update automatically.

Comment: Could you please guide me on ensuring that the VBA solution remains compatible with both the Microsoft Word 16.0 and Microsoft Word 14.0 references simultaneously?

Comment: You create the solution using a reference to Word 14. If used on a pc with Word 16 the reference will automatically update.